# use limit is very slow if data is none

Tags: postgresql

the sql is very simple. 
"orders_express_idx" btree (express).  express is index.

works well. because express a is exists.

```
select * from orders where express =  'a'  order by id desc limit 1;

Limit  (cost=0.43..1.29 rows=1 width=119)
->  Index Scan Backward using orders_pkey on orders  (cost=0.43..4085057.23 rows=4793692 width=119)
     Filter: ((express)::text = 'a'::text)
```

works slow. data is nonexistent. and I use limit.

```
select * from orders where express =  'b'  order by id desc limit 1;

 Limit  (cost=0.43..648.86 rows=1 width=119)
 ->  Index Scan Backward using orders_pkey on orders  (cost=0.43..4085061.83 rows=6300 width=119)
     Filter: ((express)::text = 'a'::text)
```

works well. data is nonexistent. but I didn't use limit.

```
select * from orders where express =  'b'  order by id desc;

Sort  (cost=24230.91..24246.66 rows=6300 width=119)
Sort Key: id
->  Index Scan using orders_express_idx on orders  (cost=0.56..23833.35 rows=6300 width=119)
     Index Cond: ((express)::text = 'a'::text)
```

Comment: Please include the query plans also (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)

Comment: Using a limit will not make a query execution faster. It will just stop returning rows at a certain time. Chances are running it without a limit hit an internal cache.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `orders` (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/using-explain.html

go to the seciotn with

> Here is an example showing the effects of LIMIT:

and further:

> This is the same query as above, but we added a LIMIT so that not all
>   the rows need be retrieved, and the planner changed its mind about
>   what to do. Notice that the total cost and row count of the Index Scan
>   node are shown as if it were run to completion. However, the Limit
>   node is expected to stop after retrieving only a fifth of those rows,
>   so its total cost is only a fifth as much, and that's the actual
>   estimated cost of the query. This plan is preferred over adding a
>   Limit node to the previous plan because the Limit could not avoid
>   paying the startup cost of the bitmap scan, so the total cost would be
>   something over 25 units with that approach.

So basically - yes. adding `LIMIT` changes the plan and thus it can become more effective for smaller data set (expected), but also the impact can be negative (depending on statistics and settings (scan cost, effective_cache_size and so on)...

If you give the execution plans for queries above we would explain WHAT happens.  But basically this is documented behaviour - `LIMIT` changes the plan and thus execution time - yes.

Comment: we need `explain analyze select`, not just `explain select`, please